# Solve $(1+i)^z = i$ where $z$ is a complex number.

Tags: complex-numbers

How can I solve this equation?

$$(1+i)^z = i$$

The only way I can start is to use $e^{z\log(1+i)}$.

Comment: what is the value for $z$?

Comment: z is a complex number

Comment: That's just $e^z\log(1+i)=\cos z\log(1+i)+i\sin z\log(1+i).$

Comment: and when how I can solve this equation  $$(1+i)^z = i $$

Comment: Do you mean $e^{z \log(1+i)}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $1+i=\sqrt{2}\left(\frac{1+i}{\sqrt{2}}\right)=\sqrt{2}e^{\frac{i\pi}{4}}$. Now let $z=x+iy$. Then
\begin{align*}
(1+i)^z & =\left(\sqrt{2}e^{\frac{i\pi}{4}}\right)^{x+iy}\\
&=\left(\sqrt{2}e^{\frac{i\pi}{4}}\right)^{x}\cdot \left(\sqrt{2}e^{\frac{i\pi}{4}}\right)^{iy}\\
&=\left(2^{x/2}e^{\frac{ix\pi}{4}}\right)\cdot \left(2^{iy/2}e^{\frac{-y\pi}{4}}\right)\\
&=\left(2^{x/2}e^{\frac{-y\pi}{4}}\right)\cdot \left(e^{iy (\ln 2)/2}e^{\frac{ix\pi}{4}}\right)\\
&=\left(2^{x/2}e^{\frac{-y\pi}{4}}\right)\cdot \left(e^{i\left[\frac{2y\ln 2+x\pi}{4}\right]}\right).
\end{align*}
In order to solve $(1+i)^z=i$, we do the following: first we equate the magnitude of both sides to get
\begin{align*}
|(1+i)^z|&=|i|\\
2^{x/2}e^{\frac{-y\pi}{4}}&=1\\
2^{x/2}&=e^{\frac{y\pi}{4}}\\
\color{red}{x \ln 4} & \color{red}{=y\pi}.
\end{align*}
Now we equate the angles to get
\begin{align*}
\frac{2y\ln 2+x\pi}{4}&=\frac{(4n+1)\pi}{2}\\
\color{blue}{2y\ln2+\pi x}&=\color{blue}{2(2n+1)\pi}.
\end{align*}

Now solve for $x$ and $y$ from the two equations to get $z=\frac{i(4n+1)\pi}{2\log(1+i)}$.